# Show different paths on instance

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

I have the following tree:

```
data Questionario = Answer String
                  | Question String Questionario Questionario
```

Being the sub-tree on the left a Negative answer and the sub-tree on the right a positive answer.

And i want to define Questionario as an instance, showing all possible paths. For example:

```
q = Question "a >= b"
      (Question "a >= c"
         (Question "b >= c"
              (Answer "a b c")
              (Answer "a c b"))
         (Answer "c a b"))
      (Question "a >= c"
         (Answer "b a c")
         (Question "b >= c"
             (Answer "b c a")
             (Answer "c b a")))
```

must appear as :

```
*Main> q
a >= b? No a >= c? No b >= c? No ANSWER: a b c
a >= b? No a >= c? No b >= c? Yes ANSWER: a c b
a >= b? No a >= c? Yes ANSWER: c a b
a >= b? Yes a >= c? No ANSWER: b a c
a >= b? Yes a >= c? Yes b >= c? No ANSWER: b c a
a >= b? Yes a >= c? Yes b >= c? Yes ANSWER: c b a
```

I've already wrote this:

```
instance Show Questionario where
    show (Answer x) = "ANSWER " ++ x
    show (Question q r l) = q ++ "? "
```

But i'm not sure how to make it show every possible path. How do i do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You want a function to generate all paths. A possible approach would be:

```
paths :: Questionario -> [String]
paths (Answer x) = ["ANSWER " ++ x]
paths (Question q l r) = [q ++ "? No  " ++ s | s <- paths l] ++
                         [q ++ "? Yes " ++ s | s <- paths r]
```

There's only one path for the `Answer`. Instead the paths for a `Question` are the union of:

1. those related to a negative answer, prepended with the question and "No", and
2. those related to a positive answer, prepended with the question  and "Yes".

You may want to use `map` instead of list comprehensions -- this is just a matter of personal taste.